# how to pass a string as method parameter

Tags: java, if-statement, ide, jgrasp

Hi i am a beginner java programmer am creating a java program that prints instructions to bake cookies given a certain string defining the size of the batch. Im getting identifier, and illegal type errors, as well enum expected errors. Please help! Im so stuck. I want to be able to use the user input of their oven size to determine which variables will  be assigned to each amount of the ingredient.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BakingCookies{
public static void main (String [] args) {



   int cookies;
   int ovenTemp;
   int cookTime;




         System.out.println("What is the size of your oven?\n(Your options are: Small, Medium & Large)");


          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


        String oven = in.nextLine();

         System.out.println("How many cookies would you like to make?");

           int cookies = in.nextInt();




         System.out.println("To make around "+ cookies +" cookies, please do the following:");

      makeTheDough();
      cookTheDough();
      finishYourTreats();
      }



public static void makeTheDough(String oven){


  int cupsofflour ;
   int cupsofbutter;
   int teaspoonsfsugar;
   int singleeggs ;


   if (oven.equals("Small")){


   int cupsofflour = 1;
   int cupsofbutter = 1;
   int teaspoonsfsugar = 5;
   int singleeggs = 1;
   }
    else  if  (oven.equals ("Medium")){


   int cupsofflour = 2;
   int cupsofbutter = 1;
   int teaspoonsfsugar = 10;
   int singleeggs = 2;
     }
   else  if   (oven.equals ("Large")){

   int cupsofflour = 3;
   int cupsofbutter = 2;
   int teaspoonsfsugar = 15;
   int singleeggs = 3; 
    }
    }
System.out.print("Preheat the oven to the degrees stated below. Mix together:"+ cupsofflour +"cups of flour,"+ cupsofbutter+ "cups of butter," + teaspoonsofsugar + "teaspoons of sugar, and"+ singleeggs +"eggs" "Then knead the dough to make a thick, but flexible piece of dough we will now shape into cookies!");//


   }

   public static void cookTheDough (String oven){




   if (oven.equals("Small")){

   int cookies= 24;
   int ovenTemp= 330;
   int cookTime=30 ;
   }
   else if (oven.equals("Medium")){

   int cookies = 12;
   int ovenTemp = 350;
   int cookTime = 25; 
   }
   else if (oven.equals("Large")){

   int cookies = 6;
   int ovenTemp = 325;
   int cookTime = 20;
   }




   System.out.print("take your dough and use the cut tool to make at the most" cookies "cookies. Place them on a tray, and stick them in the overat" ovenTemp + " degrees. Set your timer for"+ cookTime+"minutes");

  } 

  public static void finishYourTreat(String oven){

if (oven == small){

   int coolTime = 10;
 }
System.out.print("Watch them! when the timer is up, take them out and let them cool for "  + coolTime + "minutes.");
System.out.print("Your cookies are done! Eat and enjoy the fruits of your labor!");
 }




}
  }
  }
```

Comment: You have just posted your code and expect us to debug and fix all the errors. First, google for those errors and you must be able to fix them (or at least get to know why they are occurring). If you still have problems, come back and post a specific question

Comment: @user7 i have, im hoping someone can point out some errors in my logic, i cant place my finger on why my methods aren't working maybe because of my parameters? just looking for a little guidance.

Comment: *im hoping someone can point out some errors in my logic* - Sorry. That's not how stackoverflow works. You need to do your ground work

Comment: As much as we would like to help you, you need to put in the effort. SO is not a place to get your work done from others. If you had googled just a bit to check what your error means and then try to fix it, it would have done the job for you. Sure, it would have taken some time, but it's worth it. :)

Comment: Firstly, you have declared the variable cookies twice in your main method. Also, your       makeTheDough();
      cookTheDough();
      finishYourTreats(); require String as a parameter, thus , pass the variable oven as a parameter t them       makeTheDough(oven);
      cookTheDough(oven);
      finishYourTreats(oven); Also, you have declared variable inside the if block, thus they will not be accessible outside. You need to declare those outside if, but assign the necessary values inside the if block

Comment: @akshayapandey i really appreciate it. most people seem to think asking for help means they're looking for a hand out, and I am very grateful you took the time and helped me out! ive been seriously (by serious i mean actually trying to put in effort to learn and improve) programming for maybe a month now so you pointing out my mistakes has given me a lot of clarification on how to properly declare variables. Thanks again!

Comment: it wouldn't let me tag yall (or maybe im doing it wrong) but thanks as well Gayan and Ishant! Your input helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed your issue. In System.out.println() at line 70 and 104 , you have used the variable without using +variable + with it since it was not able to recognise it.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main (String [] args) {



   int cookies;
   int ovenTemp;
   int cookTime;




         System.out.println("What is the size of your oven?\n(Your options are: Small, Medium & Large)");


          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


        String oven = in.nextLine();

         System.out.println("How many cookies would you like to make?");

           int cookies = in.nextInt();




         System.out.println("To make around "+ cookies +" cookies, please do the following:");

      makeTheDough();
      cookTheDough();
      finishYourTreats();
      }



public static void makeTheDough(String oven){


  int cupsofflour ;
   int cupsofbutter;
   int teaspoonsfsugar;
   int singleeggs ;


   if (oven.equals("Small")){


   int cupsofflour = 1;
   int cupsofbutter = 1;
   int teaspoonsfsugar = 5;
   int singleeggs = 1;
   }
    else  if  (oven.equals ("Medium")){


   int cupsofflour = 2;
   int cupsofbutter = 1;
   int teaspoonsfsugar = 10;
   int singleeggs = 2;
     }
   else  if   (oven.equals ("Large")){

   int cupsofflour = 3;
   int cupsofbutter = 2;
   int teaspoonsfsugar = 15;
   int singleeggs = 3; 
    }

System.out.println("Preheat the oven to the degrees stated below. Mix together:"+ 
cupsofflour +"cups of flour,"+ cupsofbutter+ "cups of butter," + teaspoonsofsugar +
"teaspoons of sugar, and"+ singleeggs +"eggs Then knead the dough to make a thick, but flexible piece of dough we will now shape into cookies!");


   }

   public static void cookTheDough (String oven){




   if (oven.equals("Small")){

   int cookies= 24;
   int ovenTemp= 330;
   int cookTime=30 ;
   }
   else if (oven.equals("Medium")){

   int cookies = 12;
   int ovenTemp = 350;
   int cookTime = 25; 
   }
   else if (oven.equals("Large")){

   int cookies = 6;
   int ovenTemp = 325;
   int cookTime = 20;
   }




   System.out.println("take your dough and use the cut tool to make at the most"+ cookies+ "cookies. Place them on a tray, and stick them in the overat"+ ovenTemp + " degrees. Set your timer for"+ cookTime+"minutes");

  } 

  public static void finishYourTreat(String oven){

if (oven == small){

   int coolTime = 10;
 }
System.out.println("Watch them! when the timer is up, take them out and let them cool for "  + coolTime + "minutes.");
System.out.println("Your cookies are done! Eat and enjoy the fruits of your labor!");
 }





}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all once you declare the variable you should not declare them back. as example from your code;

```
int cookies;
int cookies = in.nextInt();
```

This variable declaration and initialization is wrong and it should be change like this;

```
int cookies;
cookies = in.nextInt();
```

next when you call a method pass the parameters also, as example;

```
makeTheDough(oven);
```

also in java you cannot use declared variables without initializing. in your code all the method print statements not work because of that and loose of the proper format.( use `+` for string concatenation.)

Also careful about your code flow and carefully separate blocks by using `{}`.

According to your code, working code as follow.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BakingCookies{
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int cookies;
        int ovenTemp;
        int cookTime;
        System.out.println("What is the size of your oven?\n(Your options are: Small, Medium & Large)");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String oven = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How many cookies would you like to make?");
        cookies = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("To make around "+ cookies +" cookies, please do the following:");
        makeTheDough(oven);
        cookTheDough(oven);
        finishYourTreat(oven);
    }

    public static void makeTheDough(String oven){
        int cupsofflour = 0;
        int cupsofbutter = 0;
        int teaspoonsfsugar = 0;
        int singleeggs = 0;
        if (oven.equals("Small")){
            cupsofflour = 1;
            cupsofbutter = 1;
            teaspoonsfsugar = 5;
            singleeggs = 1;
        }else  if  (oven.equals ("Medium")){
            cupsofflour = 2;
            cupsofbutter = 1;
            teaspoonsfsugar = 10;
            singleeggs = 2;
        }else  if   (oven.equals ("Large")){
            cupsofflour = 3;
            cupsofbutter = 2;
            teaspoonsfsugar = 15;
            singleeggs = 3; 
        }
        System.out.println("Preheat the oven to the degrees stated below. Mix together:"+ cupsofflour +"cups of flour,"+ cupsofbutter+ "cups of butter," + teaspoonsfsugar + "teaspoons of sugar, and"+ singleeggs +"eggs Then knead the dough to make a thick, but flexible piece of dough we will now shape into cookies!");
    }

    public static void cookTheDough (String oven){
        int cookies= 0;
        int ovenTemp= 0;
        int cookTime= 0 ;
        if (oven.equals("Small")){
            cookies= 24;
            ovenTemp= 330;
            cookTime=30 ;
        }else if (oven.equals("Medium")){
            cookies = 12;
            ovenTemp = 350;
            cookTime = 25; 
        }else if (oven.equals("Large")){
            cookies = 6;
            ovenTemp = 325;
            cookTime = 20;
        }
        System.out.println("take your dough and use the cut tool to make at the most"+cookies +"cookies. Place them on a tray, and stick them in the overat"+ ovenTemp + " degrees. Set your timer for"+ cookTime+"minutes");
    }

    public static void finishYourTreat(String oven){
        int coolTime = 10;
        if (oven.equals("small")){
            coolTime = 10;
        }
        System.out.print("Watch them! when the timer is up, take them out and let them cool for "  + coolTime + "minutes.");
        System.out.print("Your cookies are done! Eat and enjoy the fruits of your labor!");
    }

}
```